Functional equation for Weierstrass function and fractals
I recently came across the Weierstrass function, e.g., see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function, when looking at infinite sums of Chebyshev polynomials.
As per results quoted in a 2003 paper titled 'Weierstrass functions with random phases' by Yanick Heurteaux (see, e.g., https://typeset.io/pdf/weierstrass-functions-with-random-phases-4ln6nj3leh.pdf) going back to Hardy 1916, this function
$$
w(z) = \sum_{n>=0} b^{−n\alpha} \cos(2 \pi b n z)
$$
is continuous but nowhere differentiable for $b>1$ and $\alpha\le 1$.
Below, I will be looking for a functional equation for a variation of this function.
To simplify, I prefer re-scaling to $b=2$ (get rid of the factor of $2\pi$) and dropping the first term of the sum to end up with an even function
$$
\mathcal{W}(z) = \sum_{n>=1} 2^{−n\alpha} \cos(2^n z)
$$
Using yet another change of variables (basically $\mathcal{W}(z)=\mathcal{T}(\cos(z))$), this can be written with Chebyshev polynomials as
$$
\mathcal{W}(\arccos(x)) =:\mathcal{T}(x) = \sum_{n>=1} 2^{−n\alpha} T_{2^n} (x) 
$$
Then, using a special case of the composition property of Chebyshev functions $T_{2m}(x))=T_m(T_2(x))=T_2(T_m(x))$ as well as $T_2(x)=-1+2x^2$, we find
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}(x) &= \sum_{n>=1} 2^{−n\alpha} T_{2^n} (x) \\
&= 2^{-\alpha} T_2(x) + \sum_{n>=2} 2^{−n\alpha} T_{2^n} (x) \\
&= 2^{-\alpha} T_2(x) + \sum_{n>=2} 2^{-\alpha−(n-1)\alpha} T_{2\, 2^{n-1}} (x) \\
&= 2^{-\alpha} T_2(x) + 2^{-\alpha} \sum_{n>=2} 2^{−(n-1)\alpha} T_{2^{n-1}} (T_2(x)) \\
&= 2^{-\alpha} T_2(x) + 2^{-\alpha} \mathcal{T} (T_2(x))
\end{align}
$$
or
$$
\mathbf{2^\alpha \mathcal{T}(x) = -1+2x^2 + \mathcal{T} (-1+2x^2)}
$$
Of course, you start playing: $\mathcal{T}(1) = 1/(2^\alpha-1)=\mathcal{T}(-1)$ for $x=1$, $\mathcal{T}(1/2)=\mathcal{T}(-1/2) = -1/(2(2^\alpha-1))$ for $x=-1/2$, $\mathcal{T}(0)=(-1 + \mathcal{T}(-1))/2^\alpha $ etc.
I guess my questions are: Is this/ how is this functional equation related to the fractal nature of the Weierstrass function for $\mathbf{\alpha\le 1}$?
